Access Control - Synapse LakeDatabase and Serveless SQL Database
Our company is using the Synapse Link to export Dynamic 365 data. With the synapse link, the tables automatically get created in a Synapse LakeDatabase.
On top of those raw tables, we want to do some cleaning/transformation before handing over the datasets for business users. So we have created the views on a serveless sql database using thelake database tables.
Now the issue is granting access for business users. It appears that business users need to have access to Azure datalake, Synapse Lake Database and Serveless SQL database in order to read the sql views.
Currently I have given following access:
Azure DataLake Container: Read and execute access through ACL
SQL Database: Select access on views
Lake Database: Read access for the database
Here the issue is business users can read the raw tables in Lake Database. But we want to restrict access to raw tables in Lake Database and only grant access for transformed views in Serveless SQL database.
Is there a way to achieve above?
Currently I have given following access:
Azure DataLake Container: Read and execute access through ACL
SQL Database: Select access on views
Lake Database: Read access for the database
Here the issue is business users can read the raw tables in Lake Database. But we want to restrict access to raw tables in Lake Database and only grant access for transformed views in Serveless SQL database.

If you want to restrict access to the raw table for a user and grant access to the view, you can follow the procedure below:
Grant permissions on the view using the following code:
GRANT SELECT ON <schema>.<viewName> TO [<userName>];

Revoke permissions on the raw table using the following code:
REVOKE SELECT ON <schema>.<tableName> FROM [<userName>];

Then the user will have restrictions when accessing the raw table, as shown below:

However, the user will be able to access the view, as shown below:


In Synapse LakeDatabase "GRANT" access operation is not allowed. Can only add user to db_datareader role. To highlight raw tables are in LakeDatabase and views are in Serveless SQL DB in Synapse. When read access is not provided to LakeDB user can't view the SQLDB views.
